# Facing problem updating a column of a table, while the id and alias column remains same - sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook

Hi my table named 'total' looks like this,

```
{id:1,alias:tiger,status:gold}
```

If I want to insert a new row with a new alias lets say alias = 'lion' and status = 'gold' it should create a new id and the table should look like this

```
{id:1,alias:tiger,status:gold}
{id:2,alias:lion,status:gold}
```

But if I keep the alias same as 'lion' and status = 'silver' it should just update the row with id = 2 and it should look like this

```
{id:1,alias:tiger,status:gold}
{id:2,alias:lion,status:silver}
```

How to achieve it in sqlalchemy using insert command?

the id is primary key and alias value is stored in a variable a and status value is stored in a variable b, which looks like

```
a = 'lion', b= 'gold'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `alias` is unique identifier for the object/row. In this case an approach of `find-and-update OR create` should work:

```py
a = 'lion'
b = 'gold'

# find the object (by `alias`) in the database
obj = session.query(Total).filter(Total.alias == a).first()
if obj:
    # object found: update the status
    obj.status = b
else:
    # object not found: create and add to the session
    obj = Total(alias=a, status=b)
    session.add(obj)
session.commit()
```

---

See documentation:

- [Adding and Updating Objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects)
- [Querying](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#querying)